# How can I skip value and sum until meet a criteria in array python?

Tags: python, arrays, list, sorting

Right now, I have an array like this:

`arr = np.array([[1, 300], [2, 100],[3, 0],[4, 0],[5, 50],[6, 100]])`

My problem is to add array respectively 300+100+0+0+50+100 but the condition is to sum in order until the result is 150. So, I want to know how to skip sum of arr=300 from [1, 300] and then python sums until meeting [2, 100] and [5, 50] to be 100+50 then collect these two array in the same variable. Could you recommend me to extend my coding? Thanks

```
d = 0
for i in range(len(arr)):
    if d >= 150:
        break
    d += arr[i][1]
i=i+1
```

Comment: What are you really after here?  Don't think about "skipping".  State the problem.  Is the problem to find all of the subsets where the second values sum up to 150?  And if the first entry is just an increasing index, you don't really need it.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking for consecutive indexes that sum up to the target value (150), you can build a dictionary of cumulative sum that return their indexes.  Then match it on itself with the target as a delta between cumulative sums.  The matching keys will give you the ranges:

```
arr    = [300,100,0,0,50,100]
target = 150

from itertools import accumulate

sumIndex = {s:i for i,s in enumerate(accumulate([0]+arr)) }

targetRanges = [ (i,sumIndex[s+target]) for s,i in sumIndex.items() 
                 if s+target in sumIndex ]

for start,stop in targetRanges:
    print(start,stop,arr[start:stop])

1 5 [100, 0, 0, 50]
4 6 [50, 100]
```

It can also be done without itertools in a single (convoluted) dictionary comprehension:

```
ranges = [ (d[d[""]-target],i) for d in [{0:0,"":0}]
           for i,a in enumerate(arr,1)
           if d.update([(d[""]+a,i),("",d[""]+a)]) or d[""]-target in d ]
```